# Calculate ${2^{n + 1}}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos \frac{{\pi k}}{{n + 1}}} $

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Calculate
$${2^{n + 1}}\prod\limits_{k = 1}^n {\cos \frac{{\pi k}}{{n + 1}}} 
$$

It's task in theme "Eigenvectors and eigenvalues" (linear algebra book)
I have no idea.

Any advice? (How to solve it with linear algebra or mathematical analysis)

Comment: What do you mean by "solve it"? How do you solve a product?

Comment: What does solve mean here? What is the unknown?

Comment: Sorry, i mean Calculate